# TypeScript, Cannot find name declared inside if else

Tags: node.js, typescript

```
if (!challengeType) {
   const { brawl, fight }: any = await userModel
                                          .findOneAndUpdate(
                                               { _id: req.userData._id },
                                               { $inc: { 'fight.remaining': -1 } },
                                               { 'new': true }
                                           )
} else {
   const { brawl, fight }: any = await userModel
                                          .findOneAndUpdate(
                                               { _id: req.userData._id },
                                               { $inc: { 'brawl.remaining': -1 } },
                                               { 'new': true }
                                          )
}

// typescript error here
// "Cannot find name brawl", and "Cannot find name fight"

console.log(brawl, fight)
```

not sure why typescript cannot find name brawl and fight,
it could be a problem with typescript error handling
in the case of if else statements,

but if script is running, no problem has occurred.

Comment: One problem I see is that you have typed `const { brawl, fight }: any` as `any`. This is the reason typescript wont give compiletime error.
If you change the type to something like `const { brawl, fight }: userModel` it will throw compile error if those properties does not exist

Answer (score 5):

`const` and `let` are block scoped so they are not available in a higher scope than the block in which they are declared in.  You are trying to access them outside the block they are declared in.  You can declare them with `let` in the higher scope.

```
let result: any;
if (!challengeType) {
   result = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
           { _id: req.userData._id },
           { $inc: { 'fight.remaining': -1 } },
           { 'new': true });
} else {
   result = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
           { _id: req.userData._id },
           { $inc: { 'brawl.remaining': -1 } },
           { 'new': true });
}

// typescript error here
// "Cannot find name brawl", and "Cannot find name fight"
const { brawl, fight } = result;
console.log(brawl, fight);
```

You may have to fix some TypeScript syntax as I don't really know TypeScript, but you should get the general idea here.

---

Actually, you can [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) this up a bit and remove a bunch of repeated code.

```
const queryType: string = challengeType ? 'brawl' : 'fight';
const { brawl, fight }: any = await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
                              { _id: req.userData._id },
                              { $inc: { [`${queryType}.remaining`]: -1 } },
                              { 'new': true });
console.log(brawl, fight);
```

> not sure why typescript cannot find name brawl and fight

Because you're trying to access those variables outside the scope in which they are declared.  The body of an `if` or `else` is a separate block scope and both `let` and `const` are only available inside that scope (note `var` is function scoped, not block scoped).

> it could be a problem with typescript error handling in the case of if else statements,

No, it's not a typescript problem.  It's how the language is designed.  It is a feature of the language to limit the scope that variables can be accessed in.  Javascript is the same in this regard.

Comment: yeah but, why can i still access it outside the block scope of if else?
is it because how typescript compiles it?

Comment: @frostkazuma - I don't understand that last comment.  FYI, I added a cleaned up version to my answer.

Comment: @frostkazuma there is no *problem* - this is literally a feature of TS. If it doesn't throw a compilation error for `console.log(brawl, fight);` outside the `if/else` blocks, then you must have them defined in the outer scope.

Comment: it displays an error on my VS code but, it works perfectly when I run it, i do not know why, im using ts-node-dev to run my development environment. but maybe it would probably have an error if i compiled it to JS

anywaysss i understood my mistake, thanks for your answer and the cleaned up version, will be using it!so stupid of me to forget blocked scoped lol